# Delegate user's credentials from SSAS to WebClient

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, active-directory, ssas

[image: Solution's setup]

I'm building a solution that involves SQL Server Analysis Services database (SSAS MD) and an API(all in the same domain). Those two are on separate servers and I'd like to send credentials of a user that log into SSAS (using Windows authentication) to this API. What I do this for is that I developed a C# Assembly that's deployed to SSAS Cube. Assembly queries API like this:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
wc.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=nometadata";
System.IO.Stream response = wc.OpenRead(conn);
```

Data returned is shown in reporting tools that connect to OLAP Cube.
When client connects to OLAP Cube and runs this Assembly, API returns error (401) Unauthorized. Now, it works just fine on 2 occasions:

1) When user accesses OLAP Cube on the server that the Cube is stored on. Therefore it means that there can't be any client servers that connect to the Cube remotely. Seems like credential delegation doesn't work.

2) When adding Assembly to OLAP Cube, it's authorization can be set:
[image]

The goal here is to use "Use the credentials of the current user", but if I change it to "Use a specific Windows user name and password" and type in user name and password of a client, it works. Obviously, Assembly will be authorized only as this user and no single sign-on will be present

I've tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/configure-analysis-services-for-kerberos-constrained-delegation?view=sql-server-2017 in that I created SPN for SSAS's service account and I enabled delegation on SSAS Server, client server and API server. Funny thing is that after those when I connect to SSAS on SSAS server with SSPI=Kerberos - I get 401 Unauthorized, so I guess I might be doing something wrong. I also tried connecting from Client server to SSAS with Impersonation Level=Delegate (according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/connection-string-properties-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017) and it doesn't work as well.

To be honest, I'm stumbled. I feel like I missed one, small setting somewhere that's stopping the whole solution from working. Can you please help me out?

Comment: It sound like the User Groups in Windows are not correct.   For a user on a remote computer to get access two thing has to happen 1) The remote and local computer has to be in the same Group 2) The user must be in the Group on the Local and Remote PC.  If you are in a Corporate Network talk to your MIS person who has Group Policy Privileges.

Comment: I'm doing this setup in development environment so I have total control over all settings. So, what you're saying is that the user that's loging in to Client server needs to be in the Group in SSAS and HTTP Service servers? Also, Client, SSAS and HTTP Service servers need to be in the same group?

Comment: I'm not sure how many different computer you have (2 or 3). I'm saying you have to pass Windows Authentication meting Group requirements.  Services are normally run with Admin privileges so there is no issues when you are on the same computers and run with admin.  When you run with admin privileges between computers you still have to  meet the Group Requirements to get through Windows Authentication.  Or with HTTP you have to allow a Guest Account.

Comment: I have 3 different servers. SSAS service to which Client logs in runs under a domain account (so I can change it's settings in AD) instead of default NT Service account. Should I add this domain account to Admins group in AD? What kind of Group Requirements do I have to meet?

Comment: Does this link help : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/10/12/easily-create-a-sas-to-download-a-file-from-azure-storage-using-azure-storage-explorer/